# Eclipse auto completion irritation

Tags: java, eclipse

I created instance of Map in Java using Eclipse. Then I want to put some data into it using put method. But when I type map.p it suggested compute method instead of put. I have to use down arrow key every time to select put method. Is there any way to go put directly after enter map.p? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

1. Select menu `Window -> Preferences`.
2. Select tree `Java -> Editor -> Content Assist`.
3. Change `Sort proposals` selection from `alphabetically` to `by relevance`.

Comment: but in step 3, I unchecked "show substring matches" helps. Thanks for showing the way.